# Paste clipboard image data as a jpeg file in windows directory

Tags: windows

Is it possible to paste the copied clip board image data as a jpeg file or bmp file in windows.

For instance: When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (or right click -> menu -> Paste clipboard data as image) inside file explorer the clipboard image should be pasted with a default name.

Is there any external tool available?

Answer (score 2):

I expect there are plenty of ways to do this, but you can use e.g. [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)

```
magick clipboard: output.jpg
```

where it will guess the output format from the extension.